# Quel est le terme pour dire "penser que les autres pensent pareil que soi" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, demande-de-mot

Je cherche le terme pour décrire le comportement d'un collègue qui projette de manière extrêmes ses croyances sur les autres.

Il estime la réalité sur la base que les autres pensent comme lui même si intellectuellement il sait que ce n'est pas le cas.

J'avais d'abord pensé au solipsisme, mais il y a une différence substantielle entre les 2 concepts.

Est-ce que vous auriez une idée ?

Comment: Ça rime un peut avec “solipsisme,” mais je dirais plutôt que “salopisme” (derived, as used jokingly here, from *TLFi*’s “[Sans implication sexuelle] [Personne-qui-se-conduit-mal” sense of *salope*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salope))  décrit bien un tel comportement  d’imposer aux autres ses idées et/ou de s’attribuer les idées des autres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priori, il y a un terme technique désignant ce point il s'agirait d'un "faux consensus".

[Faux consensus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effet_de_faux_consensus)

[False consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_consensus_effect)

Answer (score 4):

Il me semble que votre question contient sa réponse : la **projection**.

En psychologie, la projection est

> l'opération mentale (généralement inconsciente) par laquelle une
>   personne attribue à quelqu'un d'autre ses propres sentiments

Source: [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(psychanalyse))

Comment: Je ne crois pas que ce soit l'idée recherchée. Peut-être que l'auteur de la question pourra préciser.

Comment: Ah non ? C'est précisément le mot que j'aurais choisi en anglais, et le sens psychologique en français semble être identique. (Je trouve pertinent l'emploi peut-être inconscient de « projette » de la part de l'auteur.) Qu'est-ce qui te fait hésiter ?

Comment: Je t'ai ajouté un point car tu es assez proche du terme que je cherchais. Le terme exact en psychologie semble être "Faux Consensus".

Answer (score 1):

Peut-être il s'agit du terme *intransigeance*.

En effet, quand une personne **projette de manière extrême ses croyances sur les autres**, elle tout simplement [ne transige pas](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/intransigeance/43971?q=intransigeance#43894).

Il est donc intransigeant s'il se comporte comme ça.

Comment: Il y a de l'intransigeance, mais le mot ne recoupe pas l'ensemble du concept dont je parlais.